# How to dismiss camera and navigating to the root view controller?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have created 3 views.
1st view is home, 2nd is inventory and 3rd is overlay view.
Now from home screen using pushviewcontroller, i am navigating to the inventory view screen. 
In inventory view i have one capture button. capture button will open camera on overlayview.
Now the issue is there is a button called back button in the overlayview, when i click on this button i want to navigate to the home screen, but for that i need to 1st dissmiss the camera. How is this possible?

Capture Button in Inventory View

```
   -(IBAction) btnCapture:(id) sender
   {
     @try 
     {
          [self showImagePicker:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]; 
     }
      @catch (NSException *exception) 
      {
         UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No Camera" message:@"Camera is not available  " delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
         [alert show];
         [alert release];
      }
}
```

In OverlayView Back button Event:

```
    -(IBAction)btnBack:(id)sender
     {
          app.navcntr=1;
          [self.delegate didFinishWithCamera];
          [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
      }
```

and in Inventory View, viewWillAppear

```
   -(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
    {
          if(app.navcntr ==1)
          {
                [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
          }
           app.navcntr=0;
   }
```

The issue is it is navigating to home screen but application get crashed.
How to solve it?

Thanks.
[image]

Comment: edit your question with some code

Comment: Have you used modal view to display camera ?

Comment: Crash log please. Post the crash log.

Comment: @komal how to push that view after pushing view check you release that view controller...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are trying to dismiss your camera view twice. I mean `didFinishWithCamera` method will dismiss it. Remove the line `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

```
-(IBAction)btnBack:(id)sender
     {
          app.navcntr=1;
          [self.delegate didFinishWithCamera];              
     }
```

**EDITED**

You should not perform animations when you are not on screen ("will appear").

Write your code in `viewDidAppear` like

```
-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
    {
          [super viewDidAppear:animated];

          if(app.navcntr ==1)
          {
                [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
          }
           app.navcntr=0;
   }
```

Comment: wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003

Comment: @komalmehta: what is this ? crash log ??

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to dismiss the modal view controller from the controller which owns the UIImagePickerController.

```
-(IBAction)whilePoppingBack:(id)sender{
    [controllerWhichContainsPicker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

//Once this is done, you can happily navigate to home view controller by popToRootViewController method.

PS Note: Finding controllerWhichContainsPicker is another thing, that depends on the view hierarchy that you have created based on that u need to dismiss this first later u need to do other stuff like navigating and other view things.

//Another thing is what i m suspecting is some memory leak(As u have mentioned here: **wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003**).Try running the instruments tool or NSZombie or NSMallocGaurd to enabled and try to figure out the location of leak, if the above code doesn't seem to solve the problem.

Let me know if you are able to get rid of it!